# Блокировка в чате сообщества

Tags: поддержка, чат, блокировка

Словил тут блокировку в чате на полчаса:

> [image: Блокировка]

За что конкретно, не понимаю. Кто-то залётный акцептнул флаги? Доколе?

Хорошо бы иметь хотя бы ссылку на проблемное сообщение.

Comment: О как? Тыжмодератора комнаты оказывается тоже можно заблокировать?

Comment: Там вроде справа если щелнкуть на "inappropriate content", откроется история причинного сообщения.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan ну, уже не могу, нужен новый бан для проверки :)

Comment: Примите мои глубочайшие соболезнования

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Эм.. Тоже не понимаю, но блокировка за [вот это сообщение](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=41206645#41206645):

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Т.е. нашлась как минимум пара человек >10k суммарной репы, которые подтвердили "inappropriate content"?

Comment: @alexolut, не знаю. Я вижу только сообщения, за которые была блокировка. Кто ставил/подтверждал тревоги не знаю (возможно, просто не нашёл).

Comment: Не знаю контекста, но самое оскорбительное, что можно было гипотетически найти в этом сообщении, это разве что вкладывание в него смысла "У -- уходите". Но на флаг даже этого как-то маловато.

Comment: @D-side, вроде бы он там и был, но я бы такую тревогу завернул.

Comment: @alexolut, а первый бан был за эту картинку: http://i11.pixs.ru/storage/8/9/3/8224jpg_3059074_22482893.jpg вот тут: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/0?m=36826862#36826862

Comment: От каких-то овощененавистников, видимо. Да, помню это. Прям аж прослезился, как давно это было :)

Comment: В чате вот интересные [моменты всплывают](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41212569#41212569).

Comment: @alexolut в итоге сам модератор тебя и забанил и лицемерит тут https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41218263#41218263  :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, меня в тот момент в чате не было, а то бы забаничл случайно)))