# Блокировки в чат комнатах

Tags: поддержка, предложение, чат, блокировка

При блокировке пользователя в одной из чат комнат блокировка автоматически распространяется на все остальные комнаты сообщества.

Например, если пользователя заблокировали за сообщения в [главном чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--), то написать сообщение в [любой](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com) другой комнате он тоже не сможет.

В связи с этим возникает несколько вопросов

- Распространяется ли блокировка на чаты автоматически создаваемые системой (некоторые из ограничений в таких чатах не учитываются, например, недостаточное количество репутации).
- Существует ли механизм блокировки только в отдельно взятой комнате? 
  (RO теоретически могут делать kick/mute отдельных пользователей, но такое действие привлечет внимание модераторов)
- Если механизм существует, то почему им не пользуются?
- Если такая возможность не реализована, то насколько сложно ее добавить?

Comment: `Существует ли механизм блокировки только в отдельно взятой комнате?` - а смысл? Если участник ведет себя не подобающе в комнате, за что был забанен, то в другой он будет мягок и покладист?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а если он ведет себя подобающе, но внезапно получает блокировку?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вопрос возник из-за постоянных блокировок по непонятным причинам, в том числе из-за странно обработанных флагов. Сейчас в сообществе активна только основная комната, но когда переписываешся сразу в нескольких и прилетает блокировка это действительно неудобно.

Comment: @GreenDragon как можно вести себя подобающе, получив блок? Как-то   взаимоисключающе это

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, подобающее поведение слишком субъективно, чтобы оценивать его объективно.

Comment: @GreenDragon так может сказать тот, кто не знает правил поведения

Comment: @FoggyFinder ну почему не удобно? Человек на улице Ленина пырнул ножом другого человека. Прибежала полиция, схватила его (того, кто пырнул) и сказала "так, у нас этого делать нельзя отныне! Марш отсюда на ул. Светлую!"... странно выглядит

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы исходите из позиции, что заблокированный всегда неправ. На практике это не работает. Давайте приводить не далекие от реальности аналогии, а конкретные ситуации. Специально старался абстрагировать вопрос, но раз вы настаиваете:

Comment: [1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6397/Блокировка-в-чате-сообщества); [2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5554/Блокировка-в-чате), [3](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4694/Блокировки-в-чате) - это только из тем на мете. Что касается случаев которые не были вынесены, только сегодня получили блокировку [Atomic_alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4651282/atomic-alarm), [Alexandr Kazakov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/234502/alexandr-kazakov)

Comment: посмотрите причины - вредоносный шум? допустим То есть сообщения участников мешали конструктивному обсуждению в конкретной общей комнате, но почему их будут лишать возможности переписываться в других комнатах?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, _может_. Не уверен, что понял ваш комментарий.

Answer (score 3):

- Исследуя данный вопрос, я не нашел опровержений тому, что заблокированный в чате участник, сможет получить доступ к какому–либо либо другому чату. В интерфейсе для модераторов блокировка выглядит одинаково (различие лишь в описании). То есть ответ — да, распространяется.
- Нет, не существует.
- Вероятно, не сложно. С виду, это выглядит как одно условие, проверяющее, где участник был заблокирован изначально. Причина тут не техническая. Мы считаем, что *если участник не понимает как себя вести в отдельном взятом чате, то он не должен быть допущен до системы чатов вообще*.

Дополнительные очень-очень полезные ссылки:

- [Make it possible to revoke write access to public chat rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135734/)
- [Toward a philosophy of Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270587/274323)
- [FAQ чата сети](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq)
- [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat)

Comment: Что за фигня? о5 в чате забанили.